# Recover files from a SATA drive from USB

Tags: data-recovery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to recover deleted files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3883/how-to-recover-deleted-files)

I've damaged the drive I had in my windows laptop and now I want to try to recover as many files as possible.  I know very little about linux though.

I have Ubuntu 10.04.  I have a docking station for the drive and it is connected to my linux machine.  The drive appears in disk utility.

Unfortunately, this is where I have no idea where to proceed.  Any help is appreciated and I can provide more info if needed.